# How can I force PostgreSQL to create schema with 'pg_' reserved prefix

Tags: postgresql, schema, pg-restore

I am restoring a PostgreSQL dump file (created with v9.5) which contains some schemas with reserved name, e.g. `pg_catalog`. I basically don't know how this dump file is created, but I need to restore it on the same version of PostgreSQL . When I try to restore, I get this error:

```
ERROR:  unacceptable schema name "pg_catalog"
DETAIL:  The prefix "pg_" is reserved for system schemas.
```

I need to know how can I bypass this restriction and create my schema regardless to its name.

Comment: A dump should never contain a CREATE SCHEMA for the system schemas. Is that a SQL dump (restored via `psql`) or a "custom" format (restored via `pg_restore`)?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It is a custom format from an open-source project with `.dump` postfix.

Comment: You could try to tell pg_restore to only restore the public schema, e.g. `--schema=public` (if there are more schemas, use multiple `--schema` parameters)